# How to configure users/keys to allow Ansible to run against multiple hosts?

Tags: linux, ssh, ansible, rhel

I'm currently using a sandbox environment to help gain an understanding of Linux and Ansible.

I have a rhel 7.6 VM where Ansible is installed/ran from that i connect to via moba. I then have 2 test VMs that i'd like to run Ansible against.

I cannot SSH from the Ansible VM to either of the test VM's (Permission denied public key) but i can connect directly to the test VM's.

How do i set up the keys/hosts? does the private key need to be uploaded to the Ansible VM?

Comment: See [PUBLIC KEY AUTHENTICATION FOR SSH](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/public-key-authentication).  Never ever give your private key away.

Answer (score 0):

Try to deploy `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` key from Ansible control machine to one of your VM's in a file `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`. Copy the contents of `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` from the Ansible control machine in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the target host. You may use the `ssh-copy-id` command to perform this for you so long as you have access to the target host via some method.

Answer (score 0):

another method different from best practice id_rsa.pub deployment is configuring inventory vars for your hosts/groups by setting ansible_user, ansible_ssh_pass (with vault usage), ansible_become_user, ansible_become_pass (with vault usage)